# used microcontroller reprogramming

Tags: basic-language

I have been recently been collecting parts from various machines that I could collect few micro-controllers. I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to take the micro-controller and reprogram it (to be somewhat similar to an arduino, and at least Arduino IDE compatible)?
2. One IC named as WT62P2 monitor controller. Does someone know how to connect it to a PC and what language should I use to re-program?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to these questions would be found in the datasheet.

Some chips are reprogrammable, some can only be programmed once, some have a "fuse" - you can reprogram them any number of times, until you "blow the fuse", at which point they are no longer programmable. I even have some (very old!) chips which you could program once, and to clear the programming, you expose the chip to ultra-violet light.

You describe the first chip as "Arduino IDE compatible" - that covers an awful lot of chips. If you know the specific chip, google the chip name and "datasheet". For example, googling "atmega328p datasheet" returns https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf as the first link. Datasheets take a bit of work to get used to, but (usually!) everything you need to know is in there - how much memory it has, how fast it runs, what all the machine code instructions are, what each pin does, how to wire it into a circuit, and how to program it.

I did a search for "WT62P2 datasheet", and it came up with https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/520/WT62P2-pdf.php
This says that it's a 6502 processor (slightly modified) running at 6Mhz. 6502 processors are very well documented - many of the home computers used this in the 1980s, back when computers came with manuals on the secret innards of the hardware.

It is probably 5v, there's a pin marked "VDD +5V power supply".

The datasheet does not specify how to program it, but I see it has an i2c bus - if it were me, I'd power it up and try to connect to the i2c bus. Arduino has support for i2c.

It has one pin marked USB D+ and one USB D-, these are likely to be for send and received data. The 6502 didn't have any instructions to read/write data from other devices, instead it would do "address mapping" - there would be bytes of memory at specific addresses; reading the right address might give you a byte from the keyboard, or writing another byte might make the disk drive start to spin. I would expect this to be the same. If you have one that is already programmed, make sure you make a copy of the data that it has before changing anything - you can unassemble to code, to see what it is doing. It will take quite a bit of sleuthing. The datasheet is missing a lot of critical data.

If you have only the chip, to get it to do anything, you need to hook up VDD to 5V, GND to 0V, and a 12Mhz oscillator (not included) to the correct pins, with capacitors, in this layout: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-0q_16rv2Wj0/ToJ0pvJbwlI/AAAAAAAAAJk/IE9yuSTi4Yk/s320/untitled1.PNG (but obviously with different pins).

Good luck!